# How to fix Could not find or load main class in Spring boot gradle.build?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Im new in gradle and i receive and error about my main class is `Could not find or load main class` i tried to fix it but doest work.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.9'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    
    
}



group = 'com.notification'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'


configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.3")
}

dependencies {
 
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:2.3.1'
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure:2.3.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}


tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = 'com.notification.NotificationServiceApplication'
}
```

Error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.notifcation.NotificationServiceApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.notifcation.NotificationServiceApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this post question. I just restart my IDE